# Not able to fetch all json response from server

Tags: java, regex, json, jsp, struts2

I want to fetch json response from server for that I am using following code

```java
public class AtomAddressDetail implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private Place placeByStateId;
    private Atom atom;
    private Place placeByCountryId;
    private Place placeByCityId;
    private Place placeByStreetId;
    private Place placeByAreaId;
    private String houseno;
   //getter and setter
}

public class Place implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String about;
    //getter and setter
}
```

In action

```java
public class SettingAction extends ActionSupport {
    private long pageId; //getter and setter
    private long id;  //getter and setter
    private List<AtomAddressDetail> atomAddressList;
    public String singleAddress() {
         setAtomAddressList(cdao.singleAddress(getId(), getPageId()));
         for (AtomAddressDetail a : getAtomAddressList()) {
                            System.out.println("Country " + a.getPlaceByCountryId().getId() + " " + a.getPlaceByCountryId().getName());
                            System.out.println("state " + a.getPlaceByStateId().getId() + " " + a.getPlaceByStateId().getName());
                            System.out.println("city " + a.getPlaceByCityId().getId() + " " + a.getPlaceByCityId().getName());
                             System.out.println("area " + a.getPlaceByAreaId().getId() + " " + a.getPlaceByAreaId().getName());
                            System.out.println("street " + a.getPlaceByStreetId().getId() + " " + a.getPlaceByStreetId().getName());
         }
    }
    public List<AtomAddressDetail> getAtomAddressList() {
                return atomAddressList;
    }
        
    public void setAtomAddressList(List<AtomAddressDetail> atomAddressList) {
                this.atomAddressList = atomAddressList;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Country 2 India
state 3 asdf
city 4 sdfsd
area 5 www
street 6 sdfdsa f
```

In `struts.xml`

```xml
<action name="SingleAddressDetail" class=".SettingAction" method="singleAddress">
    <result name="success" type="json">
        <param name="includeProperties">
            ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.id,
            ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.houseno,
            ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByAreaId.id,
            ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByAreaId.name,
            ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByCityId.id,
            ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByCityId.name,
            ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByStateId.id,
            ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByStateId.name,
            ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByCountryId.id,
            ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByCountryId.name
        </param>
        <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
        <param name="root">
            #action
        </param>
    </result>
    <result name="input" type="json"/>
    <result name="login" type="json"></result>
</action>
```

In JSP

```jsp
{"atomAddressList":[{"houseno":"sadf sadf ","id":1}]}
```

Problem is in JSP page I am getting only two filds value but I want to fetch all values that are specified in `struts.xml`'s action.

Values are printed in action properly as mentioned but on accessing in JSP like `alert(data.atomAddressList[0].placeByCountryId.id);` it is showing

```
error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you just specify `atomAddressList` as a `root` instead of using `includeProperties` parameter?

Comment: showing `null`     .

Comment: Try with `<result type="json"/>` w/o parameters and post json response.

Comment: showing error `org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Comment: Well... Are you sure that `<param name="root">atomAddressList</param>` w/o any additional parameters doesn't work?

Comment: Yes not showing any parameter output is null

Comment: for checking I am using url `http://localhost:8085/tt/SingleAddressDetail?pageId=44&id=1` showing null

Comment: Where do you see null?

Comment: One more try... How do you access json response? With this `alert(data.atomAddressList[0].placeByCountryId.id);`? Try print just `data`.

Comment: Can you post more parts of your action ? Getters, initializazion of the atomAddressList, etc

Comment: @AndreaLigios Added other data of action

Comment: Please add the real exception. `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` is just an extra layer over the real exception, that you will find by traversing the `Caused By` exception chain

Comment: Now it is not showing error I checked it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't included some properties in the json result because they should be valid regex expressions for each property. A period character should be escaped.

```xml
<param name="includeProperties">
    ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.id,
    ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.houseno,
    ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByAreaId\.id,
    ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByAreaId\.name,
    ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByCityId\.id,
    ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByCityId\.name,
    ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByStateId\.id,
    ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByStateId\.name,
    ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByCountryId\.id,
    ^atomAddressList\[\d+\]\.placeByCountryId\.name
</param>
```